# ROW_NUMBER to generate on PARTITION with duplicate Order By value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I am accessing a view in SQL Server that is getting stored as following from an application

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        VALUES 
            (1, 'Open', { ts '2020-01-10 23:56:12' }), 
            (1, 'Started', { ts '2020-01-10 23:56:12' }), 
            (1, 'Hold', { ts '2020-01-10 23:56:12' }), 
            (1, 'Sent', { ts '2020-01-11 15:33:22' }), 
            (1, 'Complete', { ts '2020-01-11 15:36:22' }), 
            (1, 'Closed', { ts '2020-01-13 16:43:33' }), 
            (2, 'Open', { ts '2020-02-22 06:43:33' }), 
            (2, 'Started', { ts '2020-02-22 06:43:33' }), 
            (2, 'Clarify', { ts '2020-03-23 08:33:53' }), 
            (2, 'Closed', { ts '2020-03-24 08:33:53' })
        ) t (WO, WO_Status, WO_Status_Date)
```

This generates the following

```
| WO | WO_Status | WO_Status_Date          |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+
| 1  | Open      | 2020-01-10 23:56:12.000 |
| 1  | Started   | 2020-01-10 23:56:12.000 |
| 1  | Hold      | 2020-01-10 23:56:12.000 |
| 1  | Sent      | 2020-01-11 15:33:22.000 |
| 1  | Complete  | 2020-01-11 15:36:22.000 |
| 1  | Closed    | 2020-01-13 16:43:33.000 |
| 2  | Open      | 2020-02-22 06:43:33.000 |
| 2  | Started   | 2020-02-22 06:43:33.000 |
| 2  | Clarify   | 2020-03-23 08:33:53.000 |
| 2  | Closed    | 2020-03-24 08:33:53.000 |
```

All I want is to create a row number/ WO as per the inherent order of the rows.

So my desired output is

```
| WO | WO_Status | WO_Status_Date          | Order |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+-------+
| 1  | Open      | 2020-01-10 23:56:12.000 | 1     |
| 1  | Started   | 2020-01-10 23:56:12.000 | 2     |
| 1  | Hold      | 2020-01-10 23:56:12.000 | 3     |
| 1  | Sent      | 2020-01-11 15:33:22.000 | 4     |
| 1  | Complete  | 2020-01-11 15:36:22.000 | 5     |
| 1  | Closed    | 2020-01-13 16:43:33.000 | 6     |
| 2  | Open      | 2020-02-22 06:43:33.000 | 1     |
| 2  | Started   | 2020-02-22 06:43:33.000 | 2     |
| 2  | Clarify   | 2020-03-23 08:33:53.000 | 3     |
| 2  | Closed    | 2020-03-24 08:33:53.000 | 4     |
```

To get to this, I tried the following

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (a.[WO]) ORDER BY a.[WO_Status_Date] ASC) AS [Natural Order]
FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM
         (VALUES 
            (1, 'Open', { ts '2020-01-10 23:56:12' }), 
            (1, 'Started', { ts '2020-01-10 23:56:12' }), 
            (1, 'Hold', { ts '2020-01-10 23:56:12' }), 
            (1, 'Sent', { ts '2020-01-11 15:33:22' }), 
            (1, 'Complete', { ts '2020-01-11 15:36:22' }), 
            (1, 'Closed', { ts '2020-01-13 16:43:33' }), 
            (2, 'Open', { ts '2020-02-22 06:43:33' }), 
            (2, 'Started', { ts '2020-02-22 06:43:33' }), 
            (2, 'Clarify', { ts '2020-03-23 08:33:53' }), 
            (2, 'Closed', { ts '2020-03-24 08:33:53' })
        ) t (WO, WO_Status, WO_Status_Date)
    ) a
```

which generates this result:

```
| WO | WO_Status | WO_Status_Date          | Natural Order |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+---------------+
| 1  | Started   | 2020-01-10 23:56:12.000 | 1             |
| 1  | Hold      | 2020-01-10 23:56:12.000 | 2             |
| 1  | Open      | 2020-01-10 23:56:12.000 | 3             |
| 1  | Sent      | 2020-01-11 15:33:22.000 | 4             |
| 1  | Complete  | 2020-01-11 15:36:22.000 | 5             |
| 1  | Closed    | 2020-01-13 16:43:33.000 | 6             |
| 2  | Started   | 2020-02-22 06:43:33.000 | 1             |
| 2  | Open      | 2020-02-22 06:43:33.000 | 2             |
| 2  | Clarify   | 2020-03-23 08:33:53.000 | 3             |
| 2  | Closed    | 2020-03-24 08:33:53.000 | 4             |
```

`ORDER BY` is overwriting the inherent order for rows with duplicate values. Is there a way to get passed this get the desired result.

Comment: Let's say that you had _three_ purchase orders instead of just two.  Is it possible that some of the status records could be missing from the second (middle) purchase order?  Or, can we generally assume that all POs would always have all status records?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "inherent order" in a table or view. You need some tuple with distinct values to order by. The easiest thing would be to add another column when the view is created. If that isn't possible, you need something else or this isn't possible. Do the status always appear in the same order, i.e. can they possibly be used to order by?

Comment: Records will never go missing. Regardless of whatever wo it contains it will always have values in all columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should know that when it comes to relational databases, **there's no such thing as the “Natural order”. It's a misconception.**
In fact, it's such a common misconception I've written a [blog post](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/) about it because even though it's refuted so many times by so many professionals in so many websites, there are still way too many developers that falls victim to this misconception.

Now, having said that, I assume the different statuses should be ordered by business logic order rules - and that can be done using either a table for statuses that contains a column to sort them by, or by using a case expression in the `order by` clause.

This SQL statement will give you the results you want (Assuming I've got the order of the different statuses correctly):

```
SELECT  WO, 
        WO_Status, 
        WO_Status_Date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WO ORDER BY 
            WO_Status_Date, 
            CASE WO_Status 
                WHEN 'Open' Then 1
                WHEN 'Started' Then 2
                WHEN 'Hold' Then 3
                WHEN 'Clarify' Then 4
                WHEN 'Sent' Then 5
                WHEN 'Complete' Then 6
                WHEN 'Closed' Then 7
            END) As [Natural Order]
FROM
(
    VALUES 
        (1, 'Open', { ts '2020-01-10 23:56:12' }), 
        (1, 'Started', { ts '2020-01-10 23:56:12' }), 
        (1, 'Hold', { ts '2020-01-10 23:56:12' }), 
        (1, 'Sent', { ts '2020-01-11 15:33:22' }), 
        (1, 'Complete', { ts '2020-01-11 15:36:22' }), 
        (1, 'Closed', { ts '2020-01-13 16:43:33' }), 
        (2, 'Open', { ts '2020-02-22 06:43:33' }), 
        (2, 'Started', { ts '2020-02-22 06:43:33' }), 
        (2, 'Clarify', { ts '2020-03-23 08:33:53' }), 
        (2, 'Closed', { ts '2020-03-24 08:33:53' })
    ) t (WO, WO_Status, WO_Status_Date)
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)